# While trying to retrieve the name of the uploaded document to another page it is showing empty

Tags: asp.net

This is the code, to upload a document.

```
<td class="style3">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" name="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="330px" />
            </td>
```

This is the code in vbscript

```
<script language ="vbscript " runat ="server" >

        Protected Sub save_Click1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            Call save_doc()
        End Sub
        Public Sub save_doc()
            Dim filename As String

            filename = Request("FileUpload1")
            Response.Redirect("mynew_page.aspx? Filename=" & filename)
        End Sub
</script>
```

i am redirecting to mynew_page.aspx page.
in this page i am writing code like this

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Welcome
    filename: <% = Request("Filename")%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

But at finally the name of the uploaded document is not coming. it just showing blank only. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
filename = FileUpload1.FileName
```

Where `FileUpload1` is an instace of your [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control (declared in your page markup).